# Updating VBA API to 64-bit Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

this is a shortcut API that allows you to access directly to the name box in Excel. Since I've changed to a 64-bit version I cannot make it to work. The error displayed is Type mismatch.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageA Lib "USER32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr

Private Sub NameBox_Shortcut()

Dim hWnd As LongLong

Const NUL = vbNullString
Const EXCEL_WINDOW = "XLMAIN"
Const FORMULABAR_LEFT_HALF = "EXCEL;"
Const NAMEBOX = "COMBOBOX"
Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
Const WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202

hWnd = FindWindowEx(FindWindowEx(FindWindow(EXCEL_WINDOW, NUL), 0, FORMULABAR_LEFT_HALF, NUL), 0, NAMEBOX, NUL)
SendMessageA hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0&, 0&
SendMessageA hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0&, 0&

End Sub
```

Edit: Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your variable as longptr will solve your problem :

```
Dim hWnd As LongPtr
```